# Ext js highlight text

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield, highlight

I want to highlight a text inside a text field in EXT js.
I add the text to the text field dynamically like this:

```
this.getCopyText().setValue('text to be added');

      /|\
       |
   reference
```

I tried using the `focus` method but it does not provide the correct effect.
Can this be achieved by any chance?

EDIT: Setting the `selectText` propertie of `focus` function to true does not help.

Comment: What's wrong with `focus`? If I understand you correctly it should do the trick, see [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3mt). Can you describe how this is different from what you want to achieve?

Comment: I was calling another function which affected the UI, this caused that the text was not highlighted anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with highlighting text in textfield in a window on show, for me the issue of the field not getting focus and not being highlighted was solved by defering the `focus` call like this:

```
var me = this;
me.on('show', function () {
    Ext.defer(function () {
        me.getCopyText().focus(true);
    }, 1);
}, me)
```